Microsoft and HTML4 to HTML5 converters?
I have several pages that use HTML 4, and a few that use the "Microsoft" HTML format, but I'm wondering if there is a quicker way to convert the code from old pages into a more compliant HTML5/CSS format?
Every time I try to screw around with the "Microsoft" HTML code, my page looks awful. There was a function in Dreamweaver 2021 that allows you to "Clean up Microsoft HTML", but that doesn't actually fix the code, it just breaks it. If it actually converted that code into traditional HTML, then it would be useful, but it's really just a pain.
My real issue with the Microsoft format is that I have several excel files that I originally did my work in. I need them to become HTML tables so I can post them on a website. The stuff in Word format might just have to get converted to RTF first.
If anyone can help me out, that would be a big help

It’s not perfect, but Convert Word Documents to Clean HTML (https://word2cleanhtml.com) seems to do a tolerable job of giving you HTML without the Microsoft cruft. It does some things I don’t like, such as wrapping the content of a <td> in <p></p> tags, but I’ve never gotten actually broken HTML out of it.
